# Load json file to database

Tags: json, postgresql, command-line-interface

I'm attempting to COPY json text file to postgres database. The json looks

```
{ 
"events": 
  [{                                                                                                   
     "timestamp": 1298734,                                                                                               
     "message": "START RequestId: bjn937645",                                                    
     "ingestiontime": 123456                                                                       
  }]
}
```

database columns are: ingestiontime, message, timestamp
create table event_log (timestamp varchar, message varchar, ingestion_time varchar)

Comment: If you are using [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) from Postgres then you can't do this unless you preprocess the JSON into a CSV format file and then `COPY` that file.

Comment: I tried  insert into logging.event_log(timestamp,message,ingestion_time) select FROM json_populate_recordset(NULL::logging.event_log, '[{my json here}]'); I can insert the data with this but I got a NULL value for column "ingestion_time".

Comment: Assuming `'[{my json here}]'` = `[{ "events": [{"timestamp": 1298734,"message": "START RequestId: bjn937645","ingestiontime": 123456}]` then it works here. What is the table definition for the `event_log` table? **Add as update to question**.

Comment: create table event_log (timestamp varchar, message varchar, ingestion_time varchar);

Comment: I cannot replicate the error. You will need to provide a complete example of the steps you took and the output and/or errors. **This time provide your answer as update to your question not as  comment**.